# Kendo for Angular2: How to replace grid sort icon with kendo glyphicon

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

In Kendo for Angular 2, how do you replace the grid's column sort icon, which is currently a arrow, with Kendo Glyphicons?

I tried this in my scss file, but it did not work

```
.k-grid-header .k-header .k-link > .k-icon {
    background-image: none; /* remove Kendo's sprite image */
    font-family: KendoUIGlyphs;
}

.k-grid-header .k-header .k-link > .k-icon.k-i-sort-desc::before {
    content: '\e61a'; /* KendoUIGlyphs down arrowhead */
}

.k-grid-header .k-header .k-link > .k-icon.k-i-sort-asc::before {
    content: '\e618'; /* KendoUIGlyphs up arrowhead */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default arrows in Kendo UI for Angular 2 use font icons, so there is no need to change the `font-family` or remove the sprite image. Instead, just set the pseudo-element content:

```
.k-grid-header .k-i-arrow-n::before {
  content: '\e61a';
}

.k-grid-header .k-i-arrow-s::before {
  content: '\e618';
}
```

See this [runnable demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/y7ZLqdjQpL5zbv7P3pY5?p=preview).

Comment: The demo just sits a "Loading..." without actually bringing up the grid.

Comment: I tried the solution in my environment an I still see the arrow instead of the arrowhead.

Comment: I updated the demo to use the public resources. If the code does not help, please provide more details about how your scenario differs from the demo.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is very old question, but just in case if somebody wants to use `content` with `font-family` for `pseudo-element`:

```
.yourClass : after {
    content: "\e014";    
    font-family: 'WebComponentsIcons';
}
```